# I have an issue with Authorization to consume external service in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, rest-client

When I consume the service using RestClient it's working fine but when I consume it using HttpClient get these errors "Missing authorization" or "Unhandled Exception"

RestClient

```
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        request.AddParameter("business_branch_id", "3");
        request.AddParameter("dropoff_address_line", "Remal str. test address line");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

HttpClient

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //if i use this i get this error "Missing authorization"
            //request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            //if i use this i get this error Unhandled Exception
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);

            using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(memoryContentStream))
            {
                streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                request.Content = streamContent;

                var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                var createdContent = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                orderResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderResponse>(createdContent.Result);

                orderResult = GetOrderResult(orderResponse);

            }
        }
```

Comment: where is `$"create_order"` in `RestClient`?

Comment: Are you adding a scheme in front of your token value for the `Authorization`? E.g. `Authorization: Bearer my-secret-token`

Comment: @LeiYang $"create_order" is the method name example "https://website.com/api/create_order"

Comment: i mean you have `url`, and `create_order` differences in the two implememtations. it may be obvious to you, but not the reader.

Comment: @LeiYang you are right i update the post

Comment: @MartinCostello No Bearer